# PHP double loop problems in Wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, loops, if-statement

First of all, I'm using Wordpress.  I have a loop that displays a custom content type called `events`. I have user accounts that get tied to this event in the backend and I have it setup to output however many events they are tied to on their author.php page (user profile page).

There are normally more than one event in a month and currently the code is setup to display the events in separate `div`'s. It looks similar to this:

```
MAY 2013
- 14 May 2013 Title of the event - City, State <link>

MAY 2013
- 17 May 2013 Title of the event - City, State <link>

JUN 2013
- 01 Jun 2013 Title of the event - City, State <link>
```

If there are more than one event in a month, I would like it to combine all of the events into one 'month' `div` and display like so:

```
MAY 2013
 - 14 May 2013 Title of the event - City, State <link>
 - 17 May 2013 Title of the event - City, State <link>

JUN 2013
- 01 Jun 2013 Title of the event - City, State <link>
```

I can't figure out how to arrange my loops to get the desired output.  Here is my code.

```
<?php

    $currentAuthorId = $authorID;   // gets the current authors ID of the user you are viewing
    $today = getdate();

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'events',
        'year' => $today['year'],
        'order' => 'ASC'
    );

    $eventQuery = new WP_Query($args);

    while( $eventQuery->have_posts() ) : $eventQuery->the_post();   // Query for the events
        $eventMonth = date('M', strtotime($eventQuery->post->post_date));
        $eventYear = date('Y', strtotime($eventQuery->post->post_date));

        echo '<div class="schedule-month">';    // Opening div for a month
        echo '<h3>'.$eventMonth.'<span class="blue">'.$eventYear.'</span></h3>';
        echo '<ul>';

        if(get_field('event_performers')) {     // Using ACF (advanced custom fields) I check if there are performer/users tied to the events
            while(has_sub_field('event_performers')) {
                $performer = get_sub_field('performer');
                $uid = $performer['ID'];


                if( $currentAuthorId == $uid) {     // Match the current author to only the events he/she is tied to
                    $eventDate = date('d M Y', strtotime($eventQuery->post->post_date));
                    $city = get_field('city');
                    $state = get_field('state');

                    echo '<li>';        // Loop through all events with that author and display
                    echo '  <span class="blue">'.$eventDate.'</span>';
                    echo '  <p>'.$eventQuery->post->post_title.' - </p>';
                    echo '  <span class="light">'.$city.', '.$state.'</span>';
                    echo '  <a href="'.$eventQuery->post->guid.'">view event<span class="arrow"></span>';
                    echo '  </a>';
                    echo '</li>';
                }
            }
        }

        echo '</ul>';
        echo '</div>';

    endwhile; 

?>
```

I know I need to store a variable checking if it's the same month, but I don't know how to arrange it correctly to display what I need.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
$tempMonth = '';
$tempYear = '';
while( $eventQuery->have_posts() ) : $eventQuery->the_post();   // Query for the events
    $eventMonth = date('M', strtotime($eventQuery->post->post_date));
    $eventYear = date('Y', strtotime($eventQuery->post->post_date));

    if($tempMonth != $eventMonth || $tempYear != $eventYear)
    {
      $tempMonth = $eventMonth;
      $tempYear = $eventYear;
      echo '<div class="schedule-month">';    // Opening div for a month
      echo '<h3>'.$eventMonth.'<span class="blue">'.$eventYear.'</span></h3>';
      echo '<ul>';
     }
```